# Reference assignment to a more complex variable

Tags: php, reference

Let's say I have an example like this one:

```
$foo = 'Hello ';
$bar = 1;

$abc =& $foo . $bar;

if (true) {
    ++$bar;

    if (true)
    {
        ++$bar;
    }
}

echo $abc;
```

I am expecting `$abc` to return **Hello 3**, but it actually returns **Hello** only. I'm really confused. Is there something I've gotten wrong with references in PHP?

Comment: where is `$true` && `$true_truer` defined?

Comment: A reference is a symbolic link to another variable - It can't keep track of multiple variables using a single reference.

Comment: `$true` is simply true

Comment: No, `$true` is not defined, so that entire `if` block is skipped.

Comment: Just assume it's true... Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference variable is like an alias to the same object/variable, and it can only reference one variable at a time.

I'm not really sure how to help your situation because I don't know what you're trying to do, but..

```
$foo = 'Hello ';
$bar = 1;

$abc =& $bar;

++$bar;
++$bar;

echo $foo . $abc;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you! My situation is much more complex and the suggested solutions wont work, but all I needed to know was how the reference assignment operator works like and you pointed it out.